# Почему при динамическом выделение памяти объекту класса деструктор вызывается только при её освобождении?

Tags: c++, ооп, деструктор

**Первый вопрос.**

Почему при динамическом выделении памяти объекту класса деструктор вызывается только при её освобождении?

Комментарием в коде выделил проблему.

```
    class Person
{
private:
    string name;
    string sex;
public:
    Person() { cout << "The object was created\n"; }
    Person(string name, string sex)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->sex = sex;
        cout << "The object was created\n";
    }
    ~Person()
    {
        cout << "The object was deleted\n";
    }
    string get_name() { return this->name; }
    string get_sex() { return this->sex; }
    string set_name(string name) { this->name = name; }
    string set_sex(string sex) { this->sex = sex; }
};

   int main()
{
    vector<Person*>list = {};
    Person* man1 = new Person("Jack", "male");
    list.push_back(man1);
    Person* woman1 = new Person("Annie", "female");
    list.push_back(woman1);
    for (int i=0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "# " << i << endl;
        cout <<"Name: "<< (*list[i]).get_name() << endl;
        cout <<"Sex: "<<(*list[i]).get_sex() << endl;
    }
    delete man1;//То есть без этого объекты 
    delete woman1;//класса не вызывают деструктор
    list.clear();
}
```

**Второй вопрос.**

Нужно ли освобождать память(vector.clear()), выделенную под вектор перед выходои из программы или всё делается автоматически?

Comment: Не ясно, откуда возник вопрос. Деструктор вызывается при уничтожении объекта. `delete` - это и есть уничтожение объекта. В чем тогда вопрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас неправильное понимание работы оператора `delete`. Это не функция освобождения памяти, подобно `free`, это разрушение объекта с последующим освобождением выделенной для него памяти. `vector.clear()` вызывать не нужно, так как объект разрушается и выделенная под него память освобождается кодом, который компилятор сгенерирует перед выходом из области видимости. Ну и конечно не стоит использовать в коде сырые указатели.

Comment: Как я понимаю, сырой указатели это *ptr, тогда не сырой это ->ptr?

Comment: @iwannaknow Сырые указатели - это `Person*`, то бишь противоположность умным указателям. В современном C++ они в основном нужны сугубо для взаимодействия с С интерфейсами.

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести пример использования умных указателей на коде, который находится в посте?

Comment: @iwannaknow `auto man1{::std::make_unique<Person>("Jack", "male")};`

Comment: и как теперь добавить его в вектор?

Comment: @iwannaknow вектор стоит заменить на `::std::vector<::std::reference_wrapper<Person>> list{};` так как он только ссылается на объекты. А потом добавить элементы как `list.emplace_back(*man1);`.

Answer (score 4):

Потому что из зоны видимости выходит **не объект**, а **указатель**. Память, выделенная в стеке указателю, освобождается автоматически, а память, выделенная объекту - нет, потому что его время жизни при выходе из функции не завершается.

Его жизненный путь заканчивается при вызове оператора `delete`, потому и деструктор вызывается именно тогда - как и положено, когда объект становится более недоступен.

Answer (score 1):

```
Person* man1 = new Person("Jack", "male");
delete man1;
```

Команда `new` - выделяет память под объект, затем вызывает конструктор.

Команда `delete` - вызывает деструктор объекта, а затем освобождает выделенную память из кучи.

Подробнее можно написать так:

```
Person* man1 = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person)); // ..выделение памяти
new (man1) Person(); //.. конструктор
man1->~Person(); // ..деструктор
free(man1); // .. освобождание памяти
```

Второй вопрос :

```
{ vector<Person*>list = {};
  list.clear(); }
```

Деструктор будет вызываться всегда при выходе переменной из видимости. По сути так:

```
{ // ..выделение в стеке место под переменную list
  vector<Person*>list = {};
  // конструктор vector, может быть с выделением памяти
  // в куче на всякий случай
  list.clear();
  // деструктор скрытно прописан
  list.~vector<Person*>();
  // освобождение места в стеке 
  }
```

`.clear();` - можно не вызывать.

В первом вопросе : Память выделенная в куче, не будет освобождаться *автоматически*, так как при освобождении стека освобождается место только для указателя на объект и всё.

Comment: Так память в куче освобождается при вызове delete или нет?

Comment: Автоматически освобождается только место для указателя. В куче нужно делать всё вручную.